# How do I find the [x] [day] of the month in PHP?

Tags: php, date, calendar

I hope I'm not duplicating a post; but I didn't quite know what to search for this. I'm working on a PHP calendar, and I want to be able to find the date of the [x] [day] of the current month. (e.g. second thursday, third friday, first monday, etc.)

How should I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depends on what input you want to generate this from, but the easiest answer is:

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third friday of february'));
// 2010-02-19
```